# Running Python graphics and code

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program that I'm just adding graphics to, but I'm having trouble running my main code along with the graphics. Basically I have something like this:

```
def mainFunction():
    while True:
        run code in here


root = Tk()
board = Canvas(root, height=710, width=1000)
board_image = PhotoImage(file="/path/example.jpg")
photo = board.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW, image=board_image)
board.pack()

mainFunction
root.mainloop()
```

I can only run either the mainFunction or the graphics because whichever one I make run first in the code is the only that runs. It doesn't stop to allow the next code to run.  There has to be a simple way to get graphics and code to run together side by side. Thanks!

Comment: "I don't want any complex solutions" There are no simple solutions.

Comment: That sounded wrong. What I meant was that I'm a beginner programmer and this is for an assignment. We haven't learned anything about multithreading yet.

Comment: That's okay, because multithreading isn't how you'd do it. But it would still be complex.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Tk.after_idle()` to register a function that will do a *piece* of the work required. Keep doing piece after piece until all the work is done.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how the Tk.after_idle() function works. Do you have a resource for any documentation on it?

Comment: You pass it a callable and any arguments to the callable.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you cannot put an infinite loop inside a Tkinter application. Why? It's already running an infinite loop: the event loop. Your code is the equivalent of this:

```
while <there are more events to service>:
    while True:
        <run code in here>
    <get the next event>
    <service the event>
```

See the problem? You're preventing the code from ever servicing events, and events are the life blood of a GUI.

Instead, you need to take advantage of the already-running infinite loop by adding code to be run inside the loop. You do this with `after` (and `after_idle`). This will put one even on the queue. If, during the processing of that event you again call `after_idle`, you've effectively set up an infinite loop that works within the event loop.

For example:

```
def do_one_iteration(self):
    <run code in here>
    self.after(100, self.do_one_iteration)
```

Then, somewhere in your main logic, or in response to a button, you call `do_one_iteration`. It will do one iteration of your previously-infinite-loop. When it is done it instructs Tkinter to call itself again 100 milliseconds later. When that time period elapses your code is run, it schedules another iteration in 100 milliseconds, etc. etc. You can change the interval to whatever you want; the smaller the interval the faster your code runs, but the greater the chance that you starve the GUI for events.

Note that this only works if `<run code in here>` runs relatively fast. While it is running your GUI will freeze. If it can complete one iteration in a couple hundred milliseconds then the user will never know. If it takes a second or more it will be noticeable.

Note: this example assumes your main application is an object that inherits from a Tkinter widget. If that's not the case it will still work, you just have to remove the `self` parameter. An even better solution is to refactor your GUI to use objects -- it's a much more flexible way of implementing GUIs.